# How to import an Augur account in Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, private-key, import, augur

I created an ethereum account on the sale.augur.net page. And now I've finally downloaded and installed Geth as well. How do I import that account into Geth?

Comment: Have you tried [How do I import my pre-sale wallet](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/96/42) ?

Answer (score 2):

1) Put your account file into the geth keystore folder (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Backup-&-restore)

2) Use it as any other account (https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts)