# Is there a way to manually import a private key into Mist?

Tags: mist, wallets, private-key, import, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I want to move Ether between different wallets. I have a private key and want to move it to the Mist wallet. Any way I can do that?

Comment: For now you can only do it via command line: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/465/how-to-import-a-plain-private-key-into-geth/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy your private key into a file, eg privatekey.txt

In Linux or Mac, from your Ethereum Wallet (Mist) subdirectory, type

```
./resources/node/geth/geth account import privatekey.txt
```

In Windows, from your Ethereum Wallet subdirectory, type

```
resources\node\geth\geth.exe account import privatekey.txt
```

In both the above options, you will have to enter a password twice to encrypt your new account information.

You can now start Ethereum Wallet and the new account will be loaded into the wallet.

**Remember to delete privatekey.txt after you have successfully imported your private key**