# for Mac - Importing priv key / wallet of receiving DGD address into Mist

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, private-key, mac-osx, import

I've followed the instructions below but am getting an error message in terminal `geth command not found`

- Open TextEdit
- Paste key into TextEdit without any extra characters or quotations
- Save the file as nothing_special_delete_me.txt to your Desktop
- Open Terminal, run command:

  ```
  geth account import ~/Desktop/nothing_special_delete_me.txt
  ```

When I paste the key do I include the letters UTC?

Comment: They key does not contain `UTC` but the filename. What did you do?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you import the key using geth that is bundled with the Mist browser:

- [Is there a way to manually import a private key into Mist?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2552/is-there-a-way-to-manually-import-a-private-key-into-mist?rq=1)

See [How do I import my presale wallet?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/96/how-do-i-import-my-presale-wallet) to work out the format of private key you have and need to use for your import.

And [How to see Crowdsale funds and claim DGD tokens after April 28](https://medium.com/@Digix/how-to-claim-dgd-tokens-after-april-28-1f489018e45e#.lmbctn655) has instructions on adding the contract details to watch the contract in Mist.