# How to access and import presale ether without the json wallet file

Tags: ether, private-key, presale

I purchased ether presale.  I have the public key, which shows the amount, and I have a text password I created at the time of purchase.  I do not have a json drop file.  How do I import my wallet? I think I have private key but do not know where to enter it.  Please help?

Thanks

Comment: Not quite a duplicate.  Without the json wallet file, and only the password, the ether is lost: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2637/42