# What email address were pre-sale wallets sent from?

Tags: wallets, presale

What was the email address that wallets from the pre-sale were sent from?  This is the email that would contain the `ethereum_wallet_backup.json` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found the answer in the comments of another [post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/96/how-do-i-import-my-presale-wallet/99#99):

> It will be an email from `confirmation@sale.ethereum.org`

Comment: You should probably mark this as the correct answer (click the little green check mark) so that others know that they can find the answer here.

Comment: Ah, good to know