# Import private key into ethereum wallet

Tags: go-ethereum, import

Hi I am running the Ethereum Wallet Ethereum-Wallet-win64-0-7-2. 
1. I want to import an unencrypted private key without running some additional software, is this possible ?
2. Is is possible to import an unencrypted private key using the command line within the wallet ? (Wallet UI/Console)
3. Is it possible to import an unencrypted private key using import per-sale account ?

Now I am running Geth.exe on the console while the Geth is loading the blockchain I am using another consol window to import the private key. 
The error massage is : Could not create the account encoding/hex invalid byte
Is this because the txt file is not encoded ? 
Any ideas how I could import this private key without studying computer science for three years. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. I want to import an unencrypted private key without running some additional software, is this possible ?

Yes.

2. Is is possible to import an unencrypted private key using the command line within the wallet ? (Wallet UI/Console)

Yes.

3. Is it possible to import an unencrypted private key using import per-sale account ?

No.

See [How do I import my presale wallet?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/96/how-do-i-import-my-presale-wallet/99#99) for the format of the unencrypted private key.

Could you please check whether you have an encrypted private key, and post your answer in your question.