# New to Ethereum. Just bought ethers from eBay. How do I transfer them to my own wallet?

Tags: transactions, wallets, wallet-transfer

I purchased ethers from an eBay seller and the seller sent me a public and private key for etherchain.org. I have a Jaxx wallet and was looking to transfer my purchased ethers to it, but I have absolutely no clue how to do that.

The seller said that they don't send to wallets and that everything is available on the public ledger. I can see it on the public ledger but I'd rather have it in my private wallet. I just don't like that we both have the private key.

Any guidance would be much appreciated

FNG

Comment: Dare we ask how much the Ether cost you...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import private key into ethereum wallet](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3873/import-private-key-into-ethereum-wallet)

Comment: I would not classify this as a duplicate of the above link as this new user should be provided the information to easily transfer their ethers from a private key to their own Ethereum account.

Comment: For others who read this, buying a private key from eBay or anywhere is inadvisable because the seller will always have the private key. If you're able to transfer the Ether, make sure to not use the private key that the seller gave, ever again.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use https://www.myetherwallet.com/ to import your eBay purchased private key. Then send the ethers to your Jaxx ethereum account.

You don't have to install any additional software or download the entire blockchain to use this method. And you don't have to worry too much about sending your private key over the internet as you will be transferring your ethers from your eBay purchased account to your Jaxx account.

You may want to try sending a small amount from your eBay purchased account to your Jaxx account first to confirm that you have the method correct, then send the rest. You can try using the **Transfer total available balance** option to sweep your coins into your new Jaxx account.

See [How do I import my presale wallet?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/96/how-do-i-import-my-presale-wallet/2629#2629) for more info and other alternatives.

Comment: I tried doing this exactly as you stated and it says invalid password unable to encrypt data.  The seller that I bought them from says that I have to do the transfer over DOS as he doesn't know how any of the new stuff interacts.

Comment: From the link http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/96/how-do-i-import-my-presale-wallet/2629#2629, what kind of key do you have? encrypted or unencrypted? (don't post it :-))

Comment: So now I'm trying to figure out the code that will send ether from this address 0xea38835e840942674c80ba3a99e7a77a4dfe1291 to this address 0xF8b298dfADeB0253a1E2f765C93c96B5C61d9AE8 .

Comment: I have an encrypted key

Comment: and you have a password to unencrypted that key?

Comment: With the password of course, but I'm a little suspicious if the password will actually work.  I'm just trying to knock it out now to make sure it works in case I have to dispute the eBay sale.

Comment: MEW should be able to unencrypted the private key then. If the seller provided more info that looks like JSON, you may have a wallet, where you can use the JSON or keystore option,in MEW.

Comment: Yea it hasn't unencrypted the private key, he hasn't include the JSON, just the private key and what he said was the passcode.  I guess it's back to the drawing board.  Thank you for all the help though

Comment: ask the seller to try unencrypting the encrypted key in MEW.

Comment: (1) MEW was the only one to provide encrypted private keys in text format. We ended that 2+ months ago. Everyone else does keystore or another encrypted JSON version. (2) We still support our old encrypted text format. (3) if they encrypted it a different way, you can decrypt it unless you know the encryption method. So, either you have a bad encrypted private key, or you have a JSON format (that may have been saved as text?) Does your key look like `{"address":"","version":3,"crypto:{"asdf","asdf"}`? or just a string of numbers and letters?